# Neo4j HA Unable to Connect Using External IP

Tags: neo4j

With Neo4j 2.0.1 enterprise, I am able to configure my HA cluster, start a master, start a second instance on the subnet, and the cluster is up and running.  But when I add a third node outside the subnet (e.g. can't route first subnet's internal IPs), it can't join the cluster.

All servers can ping one another by public/external IP address.  I can telnet to port 5001 and 6001 on each, from each, using each value (public IP) in ha.initial_hosts.

A netstat shows the failing instance attempts to connect using an internal network IP (10.0.100.44) for the master, even though the configuration specifies the public external host name.  The two TCP connections are for the master I started first with server ID 1.  It also shows it established a connection using the public IP of the same server.

Ideas?

```
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.0.234:32845     ::ffff:56.209.33.208:5001   ESTABLISHED 10981/java
tcp        0      1 ::ffff:10.0.0.234:42130     ::ffff:10.0.100.44:5001     SYN_SENT    10981/java
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share HA config samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to run a cluster over subnet boundaries is to setup a VPN. This solves your question on the one hand side since your cluster members are on the same subnet. Thanks to the vpn, on the other your cluster intercommunication is encrypted by the VPN.

Comment: This worked well and the instances are clustering across regions.  Thank you Stefan.